# HttpClient error when using System.Net.Http

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.mac

I'm getting the following error

```
Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246)
```

However, my `using System.Net.Http` is not throwing an error.

I'm using Xamarin - all up-to-date.

I've cleaned my project, updated all my NuGets, and ensured that my project included the Microsoft.Net.Http package.

I'm targeting my iOS project.

Referencing the following

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Xamarin.Forms;
```

Edit: Missing reference in main project packages - How do I fix this?
[image]

Edit: .Net Assembly References 
[image]

Comment: Maybe it wants System.net insterd?

Comment: I have both System.Net and System.Net.Http referenced. :(

Comment: Is your System.Net.Http in the PCL (Xamarin project)?

Comment: Sometimes it helps just to remove them (right click -> remove) and then add the nuget package again.

Answer (score 0):

**Checkpoint:**
Go to references folder of both of the project (PCL and iOS). Right click and check whether System.Net.Http is in their for both of them or not.

Both of the should have System.Net.Http in their references.

Comment: I made an edit above with a screenshot of my main project references.

Comment: 1. Right click on References folder
2. Select Edit References
3. Under .NET assembly tab - add System.Net.Http and System.Net

Comment: I see the System.Net.Http on the side, however, when I select it, the menu just closes. It's super weird. :( I added a pic to the original question.